# Do we have a monotone convergence theorem for such sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote a sequence of real numbers, and consider three conditions that it might satisfy.

It might be non-decreasing:

> For all $n$ and all $m \geq n$ we have $a_m \geq a_n$.

More generally, it might be ultimately non-decreasing:

> There exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ and all $m \geq n$ we
>   have $a_m \geq a_n$.

More generally again, it might have the following property:

> For all $n$, there exists $M$ (sufficiently large) such that for all
>   $m \geq M$ we have $a_m \geq a_n$.

So in some sense, the first condition says "its locally well-behaved," the second says, "eventually, it becomes locally well-behaved," and the final condition says, "its globally well-behaved."

**My question is this.** If $a  \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denotes such a sequence, is it true that if $a$ is bounded above, then $a$ necessarily converges? In other words, do we have a [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) for sequences possessing the final property?

Comment: Hint: if $a$ is bounded above, the set of $a_m$ has supremum, say $x$. Now given $\epsilon > 0$, use the definition of a supremum to find $n$ such that $|a_n - x| < \epsilon$ and then use your third property to find $M$ such that $|a_m - x| < \epsilon$ whenever $m \ge M$.

Comment: The assumption implies that $\liminf a_m\geq a_n$ for all $n$, i.e. $\liminf a_m\geq \sup_n a_n$. But of course you also have $\limsup a_m\leq \sup_n a_n$. So $\limsup=\liminf$, and your sequence does converge.